# How to save TByteDynArray object to SQL Server varbinary(MAX) column?

Tags: sql-server, ado, c++builder

I am having TByteDynArray object that represents some binary data (file) that I want to store to MS SQL Server database table in varbinary(MAX) column. How can I do it?

I am using C++ Builder XE7 and ADO components and would like to avoid using TADOTable since it would force me to load the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a ADO stream object with your data.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_stream.asp

Then using ADO "connection->execute" command, insert the stream object into respective table and column using SQL "INSERT" statement.

Comment: In Delphi terms, you would use `TADOConnection.Execute()`, or a `TADOCommand` or `TADOQuery`, to execute an SQL `INSERT` statement.  But you can't insert an ADO stream object with any of them.

Comment: Ok.. Understood

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`TADOQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery), you can [`Insert()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Insert) or [`Edit()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Edit) a row, then call the [`CreateBlobStream()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.CreateBlobStream) method for the desired field in that row, and write your bytes to the provided `TStream` object.